# Re- install windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I bought windows 7 not too long ago, but my laptop now has the blue screen of death and I cannot run windows. I have got a backup CD, of all the folders and files that I found in my hardrive under a folder called windows. On this CD it contains a lot of folders and a lot of files. So does any know what files I would need to re install windows on the same laptop that I brought it with. Or is there any other way of re installing the windows that I brought, if so how would i do this.

Comment: I would be trying to find out why it bluescreened to begin with. It could be a virus that did it or a bad stick of memory, or possibly a failing hard drive....

Comment: the odds of him figuring out why something blue screened is 1 out of a million, and him being able to fix it himself is even more farfetched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have your restore discs, just boot off of the disc and step through the procedure.

HOWEVER, this will usually just wipe your hard drive and reinstall the factory image that was on there. If you have any files you want to KEEP, then copy all of the files to an external hard drive, flash drive, burn them to a disc, etc.

Usually, such files of importance are all under your user folder, under:

```
C:\Users\<your_username_here>
```

The folders I usually backup for people are:
Desktop
Downloads
Documents
Favorites
Music
Pictures
Videos

Those folders will usually contain what the average user wants backed up. If you have anything saved anywhere else however, you also need to backup those files.

Comment: I will try this, thanx

Answer (score 0):

If the data is important, you can remove (or let somebody else) remove the hard drive out of the laptop, and connect it through a USB SATA/IDE connector, to another Windows machine. Copy the wanted structures and/or files, which would typically include \Windows and \Users, added with anything else you know of. Optionally, copy all ! Then, you can re-install Windows and don't care on how to re-install.

More dangerous is to re-install Windows and hope the installer creates a \Windows.old directory, which would be the old \Windows. This only works if you do NOT ask to format the main drive.

Comment: This doesn't answer the actual question. OP wants to know HOW to reinstall Windows 7 given his specific circumstances.

Comment: No, he wants to know how to restore Windows, not how to install Windows, and I'm providing an answer to that.

Comment: You give a longer paragraph instructing in very basic terms how and what to backup, and then an opinion paragraph stating your belief that it is "more dangerous" to reinstall. At no point have you given actual steps how restore the OS. Also, with modern versions of Windows, the difference between reinstall and restore is getting increasingly blurred.